# Are there any advanced bounty options?

Tags: support, questions, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I was surprised not to have a lot of choice while starting a *bounty* for a question.

- 50 points (probably based on my current rep - but cannot set less)
- No option to set an expiry date

Are there some options somewhere, or, basically, am I missing something?

Comment: You're not missing any options. You're not allowed to set a bounty of less than 50, and all bounties are a week long. If you _could_ set your own bounty length, most everyone would just choose the longest possible length anyways. See the FAQ linked above.

Comment: @pop although setting the bounty length to bounty/50*1week might be an idea...

Comment: @Tob, yeah, there could be a _little_ benefit because your position on the "featured" tab is based on the number of remaining days on your bounty, but I can't imagine that would come into play very often.

Comment: @editor: thanks for fixing the subject - but it had to be read as "About a *bounty question* ", not just "bounty question"...

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler: Although questions with bigger bounties tend to be answered even quicker, because there's more points to gain. I guess it would be better if your proposition would be inverted.

Comment: ring0: you won't notify @Simon of your comment with "@editor", see also [How do comment replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/146482)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 50 points (probably based on my
>   current rep - but cannot set less)

What size of bounty would you want to give below that? Anyone correctly answering your question should get at least 25 points anyway (upvote + accept). Also, allowing smaller bounties would litter the **featured** tab IMO.

> No option to set an expiry date

The bounty expires when you award it to an answer, or at the end of the week. That doesn't get you to the top of of featured tab earlier, though. If you want to extend it you can always add another one. Again, allowing longer bounties would:

- Make anyone answering wait to recieve the bounty if the investor chooses to.
- Litter the featured tab.